# How to disable radio button

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

Hi I have a drop down where I have few options available, and in the same page I have few radio buttons, if I want to disable and enable radio buttons based on selection on my selection from drop down:

here is the snippet of code I have:

```
<form:form action="/action">

<table>
    <tr>
                <td class="text">Please select</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><form:select path="unit" dropdown="${dropdownvalues}" label="unitName" value="UnitId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:radiobutton path="adminTask" value="${command.test1}" />${command.test1.description}
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:radiobutton path="adminTask" value="${command.test2}" />${command.test2.description}
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td><form:radiobutton path="adminTask" value="${command.test3}" />${command.test3.description}
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java or JSP? Or do you mean Javascript?

Comment: the values for dropdrown and command.test1, etc are coming from Java itself

Comment: You can set the values initially, but to change them you need a little JavaScript.